# GNOME: How to get the grouped ALT+Tab behavior back

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, 19.10, application-switcher

I use Ubuntu 19.10.

I just noticed that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not group windows anymore. I'm not sure if I did something or if it's the default behavior now. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch the *Settings* application and go to *Devices* > *Keyboard*. Under the '*Navigation*' section, set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as the shortcut for '*Switch applications*'. For '*Switch windows*', use something else, for example <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.